# Spacing Issue Table

Tags: html, css

Here is my website: http://www.gosmartbrands.net/

I am looking to add a space between each column element where the coupon ends and the next Business name is listed. Adding a line break seems to break the page. Here is the code I'm working with:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages marked home.
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @package Smart Brands

 */

get_header(); ?>

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="hero-wrapper"> <!-- Start .hero-wrapper -->

        <div class="hero container_12">

            <img src="<?php echo $cfs->get('hero_image'); ?>" alt="img-hero-01" border="0" class="hero-image" />

            <div id="call-to-action" class="grid_6">

                <?php echo $cfs->get('hero_content'); ?>                

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- End .hero-wrapper -->

    <div class="feature-wrapper"> <!-- Start .feature-wrapper -->

        <div id="features" class="container_12"> <!-- Start features -->

<?php
$fields = $cfs->get('features');
$i = 0;
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $i++;
    echo '<div class="grid_8"> <!-- Start .feature --><div class="feature">';
  echo '<a href="'.$field['feature_link'].'"><img src="' . $field['icon'] . '" alt="smartbrand icon" width="139" height="160" class="floatLeft feature-icon"></a>';
  echo '<h4><a href="'.$field['feature_link'].'">'.$field['title'].'</a></h4>';
  echo '<div class="mobile-text"><p class="justify">'.$field['text'].'</p></div>';
  echo '<a href="#" data-reveal-id="coupon-modal-'.$i.'" class="coupon"><span><img src="'.$field['coupon_promo_text_img'].'" alt="" border="0" /></span><img src="'.$field['coupon_image'].'" class="responsive" alt="" />
<h1>'.$field['coupon_title'].'</h1></a>';
  echo '</div><!-- End .feature --></div>';
  echo '<div id="coupon-modal-'.$i.'" class="reveal-modal">';
  echo '<div align="center"><div class="coupon-border"><img src="'.$field['coupon_pdf_image'].'" class="responsive" /></div><a class="download-btn" href="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/download.php?

file='.$field['coupon_pdf'].'">Click to download</a></div>';
  echo '<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a></div>';

}
endwhile; // end of the loop.

 ?>
        </div>
        <!-- End container_12 -->

    </div>
    <!-- End .feature-wrapper -->




<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And the CSS Stylesheet:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages.
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @package Smart Brands
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

                <?php
                    // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
                    if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() )
                        comments_template();
                ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: padding-top on .grid_X?

Answer (score 1):

In your [CSS](http://www.gosmartbrands.net/wp-content/themes/smartbrands/style.css), line 303,
add `margin-bottom` to your class `feature`, see below:

```
.feature {
    margin-bottom: 20px; /*this is new - choose the size you want*/
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Hey dippas, thanks for the help. Where exactly in my code would I add that? I'm only making things crash when attempting to insert that line.

Answer (score 0):

That second codeset is not the CSS file by the way. You should find the CSS file and add the padding-top attribute to the .grids with the amount you wish to separate them by.